# How to periodically back up a folder on change?

Tags: bash, scripts, backup, directory, services

I want to achieve the following functionality in ubuntu but I dont know how to do it.

I need a daemon that periodically backs up a directory, say `dir` to another location by doing the following:

1. checks for the latest directory in the back up location.

   1. If not found, backs up the directory `dir` and renames it with the time stamp to some thing like this: `dir_timestamp`.
   2. If found, checks for any change of contents between `dir` and `dir_timestamp`.

      - If there is a change, back up the directory with the new timestamp.
      - If not do nothing
2. wait for the specified period
3. go back to 1.

I sort of got the algorithm, but I dont know how to do this because I have no idea about shell scripting. if this can be done it will be really useful for my research. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You can achieve that in a variety of ways ranging from the complex backup programs to simple bash scripts (or python) that run periodically on a cron job. Here is a nice guide that might help you out: http://www.broexperts.com/2012/06/how-to-backup-files-and-directories-in-linux-using-tar-cron-jobs/

Comment: You can use `rsync -av --delete "<path/to/source>" "<path/to/destination>"` for synchronizing purpose

Comment: This one also looks http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24026/how-to-run-a-command-when-a-directorys-contents-are-updated promising

Comment: Won't the Backup function in System Settings do what you need? It  lets you choose the folder and I think it works periodically. I am not sure if it has the rest of the functionality you need...

Comment: May you try to use [git](http://git-scm.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

NB: I haven't tested this, because I do my backups differently. However I *think* that it will work.

Edit:

```
#! /bin/bash

newestfile=$(ls /backup/location -td | head -1)

budate=$(newestfile| cut -c10-19)
cdate=$(date --iso)

# Check if there is a backup done today
if [ $cdate = $budate ]; then

    # inform user that it is checking for changes.
    echo "Backup done today, checking for changes."
    notify-send -i /home/<USER>/Pictures/Logos/safe.png "Backup Status" "Checking for changes"

    # get the exit code of the diff command (1 = changes, 0 = no changes)
    diffexit=$(diff /home/<USER>/dir/to/backup /backup/location/backup-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M)-<chosendirname> && $?)

    # if there are no changes tell the user
    if [$diffexit = 0 ]; then
        echo "Backup complete, no changes"
        notify-send -i /home/<USER>/Pictures/Logos/safe.png "Backup Status" "Backup complete, no changes"
    else
    # if there are changes, tell the user
        echo "Propagating changes"
        notify-send -i /home/<USER>/Pictures/Logos/safe.png "Backup Status" "Propagating changes"
        # copy it acros
        cp -ar /home/<USER>/dir/to/backup /backup/location/backup-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M)-<chosendirname>
        # Tell the user it is finished
        echo "Backup complete, finished propagating changes"
        notify-send -i /home/<USER>/Pictures/Logos/safe.png "Backup Status" "Backup complete, finished all changes"
    fi

# if there wasn"t a folder with the current date.
else
    # Tell the user it is starting
    echo "Starting backup"
    notify-send --expire-time=60000 -i /home/<USER>/Pictures/Logos/safe.png "Backup Status" "Starting backup for today."
    # copy it across.
    cp -ar /home/<USER>/dir/to/backup /backup/location/backup-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M)-<chosendirname>
    # tell the user it has finished
    echo "Finished backup for today."
    notify-send --expire-time=60000 -i /home/<USER>/Pictures/Logos/safe.png "Backup Status" "Finished backup for today."
fi

# sleep 3 mins
sleep 500

# run itself
/home/<USER>/./script.sh
```

Old code, not as good:

```
    #! /bin/bash

    newestfile=$(ls /backup/location -td | head -1)

    budate=`echo $newestfile| cut -c10-19`
    cdate=$(date --iso)

    if [ $cdate = $budate ]; then
        echo "Backup Done today, checking for changes."
        notify-send -i /home/<USER>/Pictures/Logos/safe.png "Backup Status" "Checking for changes"

    dirls=$(ls /home/<USER>/dir/to/backup)
    dirbuls=$(ls /backup/location/$(newestfile))

    if [$dirls = $dirbuls ]; then
        notify-send -i /home/<USER>/Pictures/Logos/safe.png "Backup Status" "Backup complete, no changes"
    else
        notify-send -i /home/<USER>/Pictures/Logos/safe.png "Backup Status" "Propagating changes"
        cp -ar /home/<USER>/dir/to/backup /backup/location/backup-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M)-<chosendirname>
        notify-send -i /home/<USER>/Pictures/Logos/safe.png "Backup Status" "Backup complete, finished all changes"
    fi

else
    echo "Starting backup"
    notify-send --expire-time=60000 -i /home/<USER>/Pictures/Logos/safe.png 'Backup Status' 'Starting backup for today.'

    cp -ar /home/<USER>/dir/to/backup /backup/location/backup-$(date +%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M)-<chosendirname>


    notify-send --expire-time=60000 -i /home/<USER>/Pictures/Logos/safe.png 'Backup Status' 'Finished backup for today.'
fi
```

Comment: which one is newer?

Comment: The first code block, i've commented it and stuff.

Comment: ran the edited version and got this: >Starting backup
>Finished backup for today.
>/home/vivek/scripts/backup.sh: line 9: [: 2014-08-01: unary operator expected
>Starting backup
>cp: missing destination file operand after ‘/backup-2014-08-01-19:58’
>Try 'cp --help' for more information.
>Finished backup for today.

Comment: I should seriously learn how to format this comment.  as of now ">" means next line

Comment: Edited, may work now :).